# PDF convert local page from HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf

I'm trying to do a HTML to PDF of a local file using spire.pdf.

I'm following: http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Convert-HTML-to-PDF-Customize-HTML-to-PDF-Conversion-by-Yourself.html

I've created the page I want to convert as an aspx page which is local.

The following code works if i put www.google.com as the conversion page, however when i put poster.aspx (the page that is local) it prints a server cannot find error.

How do i use it on a local page?

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            String url = "poster.aspx";
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            { doc.LoadFromHTML(url, false, true, true); });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
            ////Save pdf file.
            doc.SaveToFile("poster.pdf");
            doc.Close();
            //Launching the Pdf file.
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("poster.pdf");
        }
```

Comment: point it at your web server with a full url!

Comment: I don't want to publish it yet / have it rely on that

Comment: i'm sorry thats not really possible.

Comment: Your other option is to generate the HTML yourself assuming your PDF utility can accept the actual HTML and not just a URL. I've done this in both WebForms and WebApi (Using an MVC View) where we generate the page and instead of outputing the HTML we output the page rendered as a PDF;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using another utility.  Take a look at this - https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

It's a tool that lets you use the WebKit engine to render a page (including exercising jQuery and other client-side script) and then produce a PDF from the completed HTML.

You could run it as a command-line process without a window and give it your arguments.

Comment: As an easier and quicker alternative to wkhtmltopdf, you could also try our HTML to PDF tool IronPDF http://ironpdf.com

Answer (score 0):

Please write the correct url. You could refer to the below line:

```
String url = String.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}",
                Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, "poster.aspx");
```